# No intellisense for Tensorflow functions in VSCode

Tags: python, tensorflow, intellisense

I've been trying to setup Tensorflow for Python in VSCode for a while now and I am constantly running into issues for which I cannot find a solution on the web. I installed it via `pip install tensorflow` and imported it with `import tensorflow as tf`. However, I do not seem to be getting any intellisense for Tensorflow member functions. Take the following example:

[image]

Conversely, the Numpy equivalent function gets highlighted in yellow and I get information when I hover over it:

[image]

Naturally, autocomplete does not work either. I'm using Python 3.10.10 and Tensorflow 2.11.0. What could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Pylance version over 2.10, install the 2.10 or older version of the Pylance. I could fix the intellisense bug by downgrading the Pylance version.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).